# Postgres - How to add revenue from one row to another when it reaches a certain sales region?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There were 16 sales regions in total in 2016, but in 2018 there are only 12 because 4 sales regions from 2016 have since been combined with other ones. Which brings up NULLs for 2018 revenue where the sales region doesn't exist anymore.

Here's an example of the table I currently have:

```
date     | sales_region   | rev_2016   | rev_2018
---------|----------------|------------|-------------
03-23-18 | US Field East  | 981264     | 871259
03-23-18 | US Field West  | 1829460    | 1289046
03-23-18 | US Southwest   | 1392172    | 
03-23-18 | US Field North | 2124654    | 2097144
```

How do I make a case where once it reaches US Southwest, it combines it with US Field West, and doesn't display US Southwest at all?

I wish to have the following table:

```
date     | sales_region   | rev_2016   | rev_2018
---------|----------------|------------|-------------
03-23-18 | US Field East  | 981264     | 871259
03-23-18 | US Field West  | 3221632    | 1289046
03-23-18 | US Field North | 2124654    | 2097144
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a case statement or you can update the record value and add the aggregation will add to the other record:

```
...
CASE WHEN sales_region = 'US Southwest' THEN 'US Field West' ELSE sales_region END AS sales_region
...
```

Or

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET sales_region = 'US Field West' 
WHERE sales_region = 'US Southwest'
```

Either way you go, a standard SUM() should work fine now:

```
SELECT date, 
sales_region, 
SUM(rev_2016) AS rev_2016, 
SUM(rev_2018) AS rev_2018 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY date, 
sales_region
```

or

```
SELECT date, 
CASE WHEN sales_region = 'US Southwest' THEN 'US Field West' ELSE sales_region END AS sales_region, 
SUM(rev_2016) AS rev_2016, 
SUM(rev_2018) AS rev_2018 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY date, 
CASE WHEN sales_region = 'US Southwest' THEN 'US Field West' ELSE sales_region END
```

Comment: It worked on changing the name, but now two rows show up as US Field West. How do I combine them?

Comment: Updated my answer